# Search for a string, replace with a cell value

Tags: excel, search, replace, vba

I want to search for a string `"xxxxx"` in all the sheets in the workbook, and replace with the value of a cell.

I'm using the following, which is almost what I need...

```
Cells.Replace What:="xxxxx", Replacement:="yyyyyy", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
```

but instead of `Replacement:="yyyyyy"` I need that to use the contents of a cell, e.g. A1.

Answer (score 1):

To replace with contents of cell A1 in Sheet1:

```
Replacement:=Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following 2 bits of code, I can now generate exactly what I want.

```
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("OAM_IP").Select
Range("I2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Inputs").Select
Range("B4").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("OAM_IP").Select
Range("E2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Inputs").Select
Range("B6").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("OAM_IP").Select
Range("G2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Inputs").Select


    Cells.Replace What:="xxxxx", Replacement:=Range("A25").Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="yyyyy", Replacement:=Range("A26").Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```